# Weakly captured self won't let the view model deallocate until the Task finishes

Tags: swift, memory, automatic-ref-counting, self

I am trying to learn ARC and I'm having a hard time with a weakly captured self. My project is using MVVM with SwiftUI. I'm presenting a sheet (AuthenticationLoginView) that has a `@StateObject var viewModel = AuthenticationLoginViewModel()` property. On dismiss of the presented sheet, I expect that the viewModel will have it's `deinit` called and so it does ***until*** I run an asynchronous function within a `Task` block.

```
class AuthenticationLoginViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var isLoggingIn: Bool = false
    
    private var authenticationService: AuthenticationService
    
    private var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = Set()
    private var onLoginTask: Task<Void, Never>?
    
    init(authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {
        self.authenticationService = authenticationService
    }
    
    deinit {
        onLoginTask?.cancel()
        LoggerService.log("deallocated")
    }
    
    public func onLogin() {
        guard !isLoggingIn else { return }
        isLoggingIn = true
        onLoginTask = Task { [weak self] in
            await self?.login()
        }
    }
    
    private func login() async {
        LoggerService.log("Logging in...")
        sleep(2)
        // 
        // self is still allocated here <<<---- ???
        //
        let authResponse = try? await self.authenticationService.authenticate(username: username, password: password)
        LoggerService.log(self.isLoggingIn) // <<--- prints `true`
        handleLoginResponse(authResponse: authResponse)
    }
}
```

So I have my two cases here:

##### Case #1

1. I present the sheet.
2. I dismiss the sheet.
3. The `deinit` function is getting called (app logs: "deallocated")

##### Case #2

1. I present the sheet.
2. I press the login button so the `onLogin` function is getting called.
3. I dismiss the sheet before the `sleep(2)` ends.
4. ---- I EXPECT the "deallocated" message to be printed from `deinit` and the logging at `LoggerService.log(self.isLoggingIn)` to print `nil` and the `self.authenticationService.authenticate(...` to never be called as self doesn't exist anymore.
5. Not expected but happening: the app prints "Logging in", sleeps for 2 seconds, calls the service, prints true, and then deallocates the view model (the view was dismissed 2 seconds ago)

What am I doing wrong?

I'm still learning and I'm pretty much unsure if this is normal or I miss something. Anyway, I expect the view model to be deallocated as the view referencing it was dismissed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time you call `onLogin` the reference to `self` is valid and so the Task commences.

After that, the reference to `self` in `login` keeps `self` alive. The Task has a life of its own, and you did not cancel it.

Moreover the use of `sleep` is wrong, as it is not cancellable in any case, so neither is your Task. Use `Task.sleep`.

Comment: Even if I remove ```sleep```, I expect that once ```let authResponse = try? await self.authenticationService.authenticate(username: username, password: password)``` is over, the logger service below that prints the value of ```isLoggedIn``` is ```nil``` or something like that. The ```self``` still lives at that point. My question would be: how could I cancel that service call if the view gets dismissed? I'd like the view model to be deallocated at the time of dimiss.

Comment: As I told you, your `login` method is not cancellable. Even if you said `cancel` to it, nothing would change. — Anyway, that wasn't the question. You said "I expect the view model to be deallocated" and I explained why that's not so.

Comment: To make it cancellable you would need `authenticate` to be cancellable and to throw when cancelled. If so, you remove the question mark from `try?` and make your function `throws`.